# Fuse not Loaded When Trying to Mount

Tags: fuse, autofs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to execute this command in terminal: `sudo mount -t cvmfs <repository> /mnt/cvmfs` and I keep getting `Fuse not loaded` returned to me. I'm not quite familiar with what this fuse in reference is. I think it might have something to do with autofs, but I'm not quite sure. I've tried starting autofs with the command `systemctl start autofs` only to get the error `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.` as well as the command `sudo service autofs start` where I am returned `* Starting automount... [fail]`

I'm working in Ubuntu 18 on WSL.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, `fuse` is the kernel module for [Filesystem in USErspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), a kernel interface that allows development for user-space filesystem drivers. It has nothing to do with `autofs`. FUSE was originally developed for Linux, but has since then been implemented on *BSDs, OpenSolaris, Minix and macOS.

[It looks like Microsoft has chosen not to implement FUSE in WSL.](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-windows-subsystem-for-l/suggestions/13522845-add-fuse-filesystem-in-userspace-support-in-wsl) Probably because it would have to interface with the Windows kernel at a deeper level than WSL is designed to do.

Instead, [Crossmeta has created a version of FUSE for Windows.](https://www.crossmeta.io/fuse-for-windows/) I have no clue if Crossmeta's product can be successfully used with/through WSL or not.